# import "adminsortable2.admin" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django

I am using python3.10.7 version of python and 4.1.1 version of django. I have installed Django Admin Sortable 2 in to my Django project.

I have added 'adminsortable2', on `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`. when I used

```py
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin on admin.py
```

the error `import "adminsortable2.admin" could not be resolved` is shown, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: verify if the package is actually installed using `pip list` in your virtual env.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. when I used pip list I have found django-admin-sortable2 2.1.8 but not resolved.

Comment: Everything seems correct to me. Try reinstalling the packgage. Is the error popping at `runserver` script, does the editor(which u are using) finds the package?

Comment: Now it works as i have installed package globally but still it does not work in virtual env. so still it is not clear why it does not work on virtual env. thankyou for response